# Sort and show array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Ok i have this:

```
array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5, 5, 68);
```

I would like it to output:

```
There exists 6 x 2s in the array
1 x 3
1 x 4
2 x 5
1 x 68
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values) function.

[Example](http://ideone.com/qsYQW):

```
$arr = array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5, 5, 68);

foreach(array_count_values($arr) as $value => $count)
{
    printf("%d x %d<br />\n", $count, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is `array_count_values`

```
$array = array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5, 5, 68);
print_r(array_count_values($array))
```

Check out the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [68] => 1
)
```